# Migrating MS-Access to SQL Server on Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ms-access

I am migrating MS Access to SQL Server (Web edition) on Azure and I am new to SQL Server and Azure. The users currently edit some linked tables directly.

Is there a way to provide SQL Server users with the same capability without creating a custom application?

Answer (score 2):

The obvious choice would be [Microsoft Access](https://www.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-365/access).

It can access both the previous Access database as well as the Azure SQL database - you only have to link the tables.

Also, normally users shouldn't edit tables directly; at least, create optimised queries for them or, better, create forms and reports to handle the daily tasks.

Answer (score 0):

definitely you need an UI for that,  there are some online tools that provide fast UI fro databases like `retool.com`
also look at this link [here](https://www.hyperoffice.com/blog/2019/03/04/microsoft-access-online-alternatives/) too.